# Crashing with no errors, sorting algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

The purpose of the program is to create a random list of 1000 numbers in an array, sort that array, then find the greatest set of numbers within (x, x+50). The program successfully generates and sorts the numbers within the array, but crashes when the (i, j) set finding algorithm starts. The program generates no errors on compiling, and I'm sure the error is simple, but for the life of me I can't find the issue. Thanks in advance you amazing people!

```
int main( ){

    int a, b, temp, i, j, x, y, tempTotal, arrayStartMax;
    int finalTotal = 0;
    int *info[ARRAY_FULL];

    for (i=0; i<ARRAY_FULL; i++){
        info[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *info[i]=rand()%1000;
    }

    for (a = 0; a < ARRAY_FULL; ++a){
        for (b = a + 1; b < ARRAY_FULL; ++b){
            if (*info[a] > *info[b]){
                temp = *info[a];
                *info[a] = *info[b];
                *info[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<ARRAY_FULL; i++){
        printf("%d\n", *info[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= ARRAY_HALF; i++){
        x = *info[i];
        y = x+ARRAY_HALF;
        tempTotal = 0;
        for (j = i; j < i+ARRAY_HALF; i++){
            if (*info[j] >= x || *info[j] <= y) {
                tempTotal++;
            }
            if (tempTotal > finalTotal) {
                arrayStartMax = *info[i];
                finalTotal = tempTotal;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Interval should start at %d for maximum numbers in a set.", arrayStartMax);

}
```

For the purpose of this program I would like to mention that ARRAY_FULL = 100 and ARRAY_HALF = 50.

Comment: `for (j = i; j < i+ARRAY_HALF; i++){` : `i++` --> `j++` ?

Comment: Also I suggest `int *info[ARRAY_FULL];` --> `int info[ARRAY_FULL];`

Comment: I knew it would be simple.... thanks you helped a ton!

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (by us humans, the computer doesn't care) 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both) names like a, b, x, y are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem (as this question is), post the `#include` statements, the `#define` statements, etc.  Do not leave us to guess what you actually used.

Comment: before calling `rand()`, should call (just once) `srand()` to provide a random seed, other wise the same sequence of random values will be produced each time.  A common method is: `srand( (unsigned)time(void) );`

Comment: this kind of statement: `*info[i]=rand()%1000;` might not do what you seem to be expecting.  This is due to the `precedence` of the C operators.  suggest: `*(info[i]) = rand()%1000;`

Comment: regarding: `y = x+ARRAY_HALF;`  Arrays in C are indexed from 0 to number of elements in array -1  which is a consideration for some of the posted code.  However, this statement is simply adding `ARRAY_HALF` to the value found in `x`

Comment: since the values in the array range from 0 to 999, and since the array is sorted, the only possible set of 50 max values is in array index 49 to array index 99.  So all the messy calculations in the last 1/2 of the posted code can be eliminated

Comment: @user3629249: A stream of 9 (valid) comments about coding style etc should probably be converted into a single answer.

Comment: It is curious that you state that you're working with 1000 numbers, but ARRAY_FULL is 100 and ARRAY_HALF is 50.  Also, if you make an MCVE ([MCVE]), then your comment would be unnecessary; the values would be shown.  Please create an MCVE in future — it won't be much bigger than the code you showed anyway (10 extra lines?).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  'style' items should NOT be in an answer.  And not all my comments were about style.  For instance, the `y = x+ARRAY_HALF` is a coding problem and the `0 to 999`' is a logic error. and `srand()` is a programming error and the missing `#include` and `#define` are problems with the question and missing key code statements regarding the heap allocation functions is a coding error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing segfault because you're walking i out of bounds in this for loop.

```
for (j = i; j < i+ARRAY_HALF; i++){
        if (*info[j] >= x || *info[j] <= y) {
            tempTotal++;
        }
        if (tempTotal > finalTotal) {
            arrayStartMax = *info[i];
            finalTotal = tempTotal;
        }
```

You set j = i then increment i prior to the comparison. So j will always be less than i.

Limit i in the comparison section of the for loop and it won't segfault.

I don't think the comparison is doing what you want, but you should be able to find your way home from here.